# MacBook MiniDisplay to HDMI does not work

Tags: macos, display, displayport, hdmi

I have:

- a MacBook Pro (6,2) Mid 2010
- OSX 10.8.3
- a Mini DisplayPort (I think) to HDMI Adapter
- an HDTV

When I plug the whole thing together, my laptop flashes blue for a second, the TV detects that I've plugged an HDMI input, but then says "No Signal".

I've tried with 2 different TVs.

I'm trying to find out who's fault it is. The OS, the adapter, or the cable?
I don't have another cable or adapter around. I'm looking for ideas...

Comment: Take all three items to an Apple Store (adapter, cable, laptop). Tell a Specialist there about your issues. They should allow you to isolate the issue, and since they have an HDTV on display it should be relatively easy for them to try alternate laptops, adapters, cables. I can't promise you this will work, but when I worked at an Apple Store we suggested this kind of solution to people all the time.

Comment: I am currently in a country that has no Apple Store :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the adapter.  I have had cheap ($10) ones go out.

One solution is to buy the Apple brand ($30 ?).  I chose instead to buy two $5 replacements.  So far no problem, and the benefit of having extra ones is I can keep one at work, keep one at home without having to (remember to) unplug it, and also have one I carry with me incase I need to project somewhere.

Comment: I confirm that I bought a new adapter and things work fine now.